# What can I do about a (possibly) nonfunctional server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, web-server, wordpress, website

**We're back online.** <del>I still don't know what happened though.</del> The power went out...

---

My school's website, (formerly) located at [www.petagimnazija.hr](http://www.petagimnazija.hr/), seems to be down.

When I try to load it in a browser, it hangs for a minute or two, and then displays the usual "Server not found" Firefox page.

I tried `ping`ing the site, however I got this error message: `ping: unknown host www.petagimnazija.hr`.

Traceroute says this:

> www.petagimnazija.hr: Name or service not known Cannot handle "host"
>   cmdline arg `www.petagimnazija.hr' on position 1 (argc 1)

The only command that seems to be giving me any sort of info is `whois`, however I believe it's fetching data from cache. It gave me the date the domain will expire (in about a year), some info about my school (street address) and some other coded information that I'd share if necessary (without the names though).

As I'm the guy who installed had WordPress last night, I feel that I'll be the one who'll burn for this. Is there anything that I could do to extract more information and check which part of the network isn't functioning?

Could it be that our web server had crashed? Is it something to do with the DNS? I've checked with a couple of friends as well, it's down for them as well.

I highly doubt it that WordPress is to be blamed though.

I believe we're running Windows Server 2008. I could get physical access to the machines tomorrow, but that'd be too late I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, your DNS isn't working: try your site in http://www.whatsmydns.net/  also `some other coded information that I'd share if necessary (without the names though).` - WHOIS information is public, if you need to hide the names, take your domain name out of your question and buy your domain registrar's privacy service so it registers under their name instead.

Comment: I'm confused. You had a web server, and it was working. You installed Wordpress, and now its down. It also sounds like you changed DNS. You don't know the OS, and don't have remote access.

Comment: @DanBig: I logged in via FTP and put WP there for testing. I didn't mess with any networking configuration, the main site or anything like that. I did have remote access until, well, it went down.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: OK, thanks for sharing that tool with me. Could you tell me whether this could have been caused by my WordPress installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I access the URL www.petagimnazija.hr it is up and available.  Based on your DNS settings you only have a single DNS server registered.  That DNS server is the same machine as your web server (which is usually a bad idea).  If the DNS Service had crashed and didn't come back online correctly then the website would have been down with the error messages which you said.  Or Windows failed and went offline, or your router went down, or your ISP to the web server went down, etc.

As for WordPress causing this problem, no that isn't the root cause.

Comment: +1 for giving me a lot of useful hints and answering The WordPress Question. I will probably accept this answer tomorrow.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could tell me how you obtained the information that the DNS server is the same as our web server.

Comment: I simply used the nslookup command line application on my Windows laptop.  By changing the type to return the name server it game me the DNS server that you are using.  When I pulled up the IP address for that server it told me that the IP address is the same.